# Suspicious pgrep run as root user on debian bullseye

Tags: debian, security, process, tracing, pgrep

I experience quite a bit of fan activity on my laptop, even the machine should be idle. When I take a look at my processes with `top` I have a `pgrep` process appear once in a while, taking some CPU. It is run as `root` user. Does anyone know what this is for? **Is it something to be aware of, or is it just a normal system routine?**

[image]

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
            Kernel: Linux 5.6.0-2-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

I run a  `while true; do pgrep -au root | grep pgrep; done` loop to see when it is launched. The `log` looks like this:

```
22713 pgrep -n startx
22713 pgrep -n startx
22767 pgrep -n startx
22767 pgrep -n startx[...]
```

**is there a way I can see what initiates the process?**

---

**Update:** running the [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592175/240990) from @hauke-laging I can see that `/etc/acpi/power.sh` seems to be the parent process:

```
-------------------------
10359 10358 root     root     pgrep -n startx
parent process:
10358  5645 root     root     /bin/sh /etc/acpi/power.sh
```

here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -f /usr/share/acpi-support/key-constants || exit 0

. /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs
. /usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs

if { CheckPolicy || CheckUPowerPolicy; }; then
    exit
fi
```

`cat /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs | grep pgrep` **there we go:**

```
startx=$(pgrep -n startx || :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `awk` variables to `root` and `pgrep`.

```
$ /bin/ps -eo pid,ppid,user,euser,args |
    awk -v user=hl -v procname=kwalletd5 '{ a[$1]=$0; }; '\
'( $3==user || $4==user ) && $5 ~ procname '\
'{ print "-------------------------"; print; print "parent process:"; print a[$2]; }'

-------------------------
 4730  2725 hl       hl       /usr/bin/kwalletd5
parent process:
 2725     1 hl       hl       /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
-------------------------
30655     1 hl       hl       /usr/bin/kwalletd5
parent process:
    1     0 root     root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 31
```

Comment: Awesome command, THX a lot! the parent process is `/etc/acpi/power.sh`